# selection in a loop freezes my page

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

i'm a complete newbie when it comes to Js, trying to make some very simple script that takes a string of binary numbers from a txt document on my server using ajax, to then put it in a string var and change the first 0 it finds in a 1, using an if construct inside a loop.

Problem is, when the page tries to execute the if line, it simply freezes. Taking the same if construct out of the loop, the script is executed no problem, so i'm guessing it has something to do with either that or/and some fundamental misunderstanding of how Js scripts works in the first place.

Here is the script:

```
    function loadPos() 
    {                           
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();           
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "posizioni.txt", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }      

    function takeFirst()
    {
        var i=0;
        var check=false;
        var oldPos=[];

        loadPos();
        oldPos = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;

        for(i=0;!check||i<10;i++)
        {
            if(oldPos[i]=="0")
            {
                oldPos[i]="1";
                check=true;
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=oldPos;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any use of loop in it if you can achieve the same without it. Please update your function to the following:

```
    function takeFirst()
    {
        loadPos();
        var oldPos = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;

        if(oldPos.indexOf("0") > -1){
            oldPos = oldPos.replace('0', '1');
        }

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = oldPos;
    }
```

Comment: uh just having a bit of problem, after pressing the button that executes the script for some reason the number in the demo element changes for half a second and then changes back to the starting value, any ideas why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `for(i=0;!check && i<10;i++)`.
But there is another way to do this using `break;`

```
  function loadPos() 
    {                           
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();           
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "posizioni.txt", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }      

    function takeFirst()
    {
        var i=0;
        var oldPos=[];

        loadPos();
        oldPos = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;

        for(i=0;i<10;++i)
        {
            if(oldPos[i]=="0")
            {
                oldPos[i]="1";
                break;
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=oldPos;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the i<10 condition is a debug leftover, unfortunally however the code inside the if isn't even executed, it just freezes the moment i push the button tied to takeFirst(), tried to add a break just in case but to no avail.

Comment: My code change prevents the infinite loop. If the `if` doesn't trigger, it is a second problem. Show the HTML,maybe.